# Árvore de categorias no MongoDB, como modelar?

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados, mongodb, lumen

Boa noite, pessoal.

Como o MongoDB muda muita nossa maneira de modelar um banco da dados, me deparei com uma dúvida que pode ser até meio besta.

Estou fazendo uma Restful API utilizando o Lumen e o MongoDB como base de dados,e quero criar uma coleção de categorias de produtos, e estas categorias tem suas respectivas categorias mães e filhas. Como no exemplo abaixo:

- categoria mãe

  - categoria filha
  - categoria filha

    - categoria filha
    - categoria filha
  - categoria filha
- categoria mãe

  - categoria filha
  - categoria filha
  - categoria filha

Como seria a maneira mais correta de esquematizar isso numa só coleção?
Ou a forma mais correta seria, de alguma maneira, colocar estas categorias dentro da coleção de produtos?

Comment: O mais correto depende do modelo de negócios. Um tipo de estrutura X pode não ser adequada para um modelo de negócios X, mas pode ser a melhor opção para um modelo Y. A questão da forma como está, torna-se ampla e suscetível a respostas baseadas em opiniões.

Comment: Apenas para ajudar, pesquise sobre "adjacency" e "nested". Exemplo nesse artigo: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: A partir do link que você me sugeriu consegui reformular minha pergunta ao google, e não pra minha supresa, a resposta estava na própria documentação do MongoDB. Postarei como resposta para esta pergunta para ajudar os demais. Valeu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na própria documentação do MongoDB existem 5 padrões que você pode seguir dependendo de sua aplicação ou gosto.

Considerando a seguinte imagem, vou citar dois padrões que estão disponíveis na documentação do Mongo: 
[image: Estrutura em árvore]

*Child Reference*:

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", children: [] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "dbm", children: [] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", children: [ "MongoDB", "dbm" ] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", children: [] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", children: [ "Databases", "Languages" ] } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", children: [ "Programming" ] } )
```

E o *Parent Reference*:

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "dbm", parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", parent: "Books" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", parent: null } )
```

Fonte: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, também irei estudar sobre como bancos não relacionais funcionam e sua resposta foi muito útil, a imagem que você postou era o que imaginava. +1